# Implicit conversion from int to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void f(std::shared_ptr<int> sp) {}

template <typename FuncType, typename PtrType>
auto call_f(FuncType f, PtrType p) -> decltype(f(p))
{
    return f(p);
}

int main()
{
    f(0); // doesn't work for any other int != 0, thanks @Rupesh
    // call_f(f, 0); // error, cannot convert int to shared_ptr
}
```

In the first line in `main()`, the integer `0` is converted to a `std::shared_ptr<int>` and the call `f(0)` succeeds without any problem. However, using a template to call the function make things different. Second line will not compile anymore, the error being

```
error: could not convert 'p' from 'int' to 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the first call succeed and the second doesn't? Is there anything I'm missing here?
2. I don't understand also how the conversion from `int` to `std::shared_ptr` is being performed in the call `f(0)`, as it looks like `std::shared_ptr` has only explicit constructors.

PS: A variant of this example appears in Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++* Item 8, as a way of protecting such calls with `nullptr`.

Comment: @@vsoftco you should mention that it is working only for `f(0)`, apart from zero nothing is compiling, same error for other values even in first call.

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) hints at an explanation - "There exist implicit conversions from nullptr to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type. Similar conversions exist for any value of type std::nullptr_t as well as for the macro NULL, the null pointer constant." But it would be interesting to see it explained with standard references and more clarity.

Comment: @RupeshYadav. done. Indeed, it is very weird, looks like some kind of implicit pointer conversion is being performed.

Comment: yes of course, and answers would be interesting.

Comment: Zero is very convertible in C++, things like f(false) and f('\0') should work as well AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) has a constructor that takes *std::nullptr_t*, literal `0` is a null pointer constant that is convertiable to *std::nullptr_t* from the draft C++ standard section `4.10` *[conv.ptr]* (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> **A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t**. A null pointer constant can be converted to a
>   pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is
>   distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function
>   pointer type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion.
>   Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. The
>   conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified
>   type is a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer
>   conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). **A null
>   pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type std::nullptr_t**. [ Note: The resulting prvalue is not a null
>   pointer value. —end note ]

in your second case `p` is being deduced as type *int* which although has the value zero is no longer a null pointer constant and so does not fit the same case.

As T.C. points out the wording was changed with [DR 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3714.html#903) which requires an integer literal with value zero as opposed to an *integral constant expression* which evaluates to zero:

> A null pointer constant is an **integer literal (2.14.2) with value
>   zero** or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant
>   can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer
>   value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of
>   object pointer or function pointer type.

Comment: Might want to use a more updated draft (see @Casey's answer below). IIRC "integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero" includes such gems as `(3 * 5 + 8 - 7) / 4 - 4`, and interacts weirdly with overload resolution for nondependent calls involving non-type template arguments, so they changed it to literal zero only in a DR.

Comment: @BenVoigt seems like it, although I agree I would prefer a literal zero. Perhaps supporting integral constant expressions for a time being as an extension would help.

Answer (score 2):

Per [conv.ptr]/1 (quoting N4296 here):

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. ... A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

`shared_ptr` has a non-explicit constructor that accepts `std::nullptr_t` per [util.smartptr.shared.const]/1:

```
constexpr shared_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept : shared_ptr() { }
```

which constructs an empty, non-owning `shared_ptr`.

When you call `f(0)` directly, `0` is a *null pointer constant* that is implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<int>` by the above constructor. When you instead call `call_f(f, 0)`, the type of the literal 0 is deduced to `int` and of course an `int` cannot be converted to a `shared_ptr<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

The firs call f(0) is compiled as f(nullptr), which is fine for the compiler (but it should not be in my opinion). The second call will create declaration for a function to work on any int, which is illegal.

Funny thing is, that even this code works:

```
f(3-3);
f(3*0);
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense after reading the answers above. The code `f(3-3)` is ok, since `3-3` or `3*0` is a prvalue evaluated to 0. "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t." On the other hand, `int x = 0; f(x);` won't work anymore, since `x` is not a 0 prvalue anymore but a lvalue, hence not a null pointer constant anymore.